# Conditional addClass not working for each elements with same class

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Les say I have some buttons with same class. On page load I am checking some value using ajax for each button. Depending on returned value of ajax request I want to add some class to the buttons, but it is not working,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.add-remove-permissoion').each(function(){
        var child = $(this).val();
        var parent = $('#parent-name').text();
        $.get('my-url', function(data){
            if(data == 1){
                $(this).addClass('glyphicon glyphicon-ok');
            }else{
                $(this).addClass('emptybox-blank');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

I have checked that my ajax request is returning correct data. What is that I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` in the context of the `$.get` handler doesn't refer to the element of the current iteration. Each function has it's own `this` value. You have several options.

1. Use the second parameter of the `each` callback.

   ```
   $('.add-remove-permissoion').each(function(index, element) {
   ```
2. Use `$.proxy` or `Function.prototype.bind` method for setting the `this` value of the handler.

   ```
   $.get('my-url', function(data) {
       // ...
   }.bind(this));
   ```
3. Cache the `this` value of the `each` handler and use it in your `$.get` handler.

   ```
   var elem = this;
   $.get('my-url', function(data) {
       // ...
       $(elem)...
   });
   ```

Also note that there is a syntax error in your code:

```
$.get('my-url'}, function(data){
// -----------^
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the this reference inside the ajax callback, in the `success` callback `this` refers to the `jqXHR` object not the dom element reference that is why it is not working.

You can use a closure variable as given below to fix the problem

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.add-remove-permissoion').each(function () {
        var $this = $(this),
            child = $this.val();
        var parent = $('#parent-name').text();
        $.get('my-url', {}, function (data) {
            if (data == 1) {
                $this.addClass('glyphicon glyphicon-ok');
            } else {
                $this.addClass('emptybox-blank');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: you used $ sign in a variable, $this, I think you need to correct that.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is `$(this)` within ajax call does not refer to the button clicked.

Replace `$(this).addClass` with `myElement.addClass`. Create `myElement` within click event just before the ajax call: `var myElement = $(this)`.